# VBA - Refer to CheckBox from the cell address

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I am looping through few rows and I need to know if the CheckBox in each row is "Checked" or not, but I don't know the name of the CheckBox. The below code is just to illustrate the problem:

```
Sub Checkboxes()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Input Data")
Dim Switch As Boolean

For i = 4 To 8
    Switch = ws.Cells(i, 11).CheckboxValue
    MsgBox Switch
Next i


End Sub
```

To create the checkboxes I did the following:

1. Create a CheckBox
2. Place it in a cell
3. Copy below in the same column

I assume the code should be the exact opposite of:

```
CheckBox1.LinkedCell
```

Comment: Firstly your code is looping through columns not rows and secondly the checkboxes created under developer tab are separate objects that are not connected to the worksheet cells

Comment: Thanks for noticing the loop mistake. For your second point: can you propose a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good workaround. The code links all CheckBoxes to the cell that they're in and gives them Boolean value (TRUE/FALSE). For visual appearance, I have used "Number Formating" that makes the text "TRUE/FALSE" invisible. All you need to do is call the function with the Worksheet (where the CheckBoxes are) as input. The idea came from [Aeneas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6593650/aeneas)

```
Public Function Link_Checkboxes_To_Cells(ws As Worksheet)

'This function is linking the checkboxes to the cells that they are in, so that the value of the cell becomes TRUE/FALSE when using the checkbox within.
'Meanwhile, I have manually made the text invisible in the cells with checkboxes, using the following method:
' https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hide-or-display-cell-values-c94b3493-7762-4a53-8461-fb5cd9f05c33#bm1
' Number Type ---> Custom --> Then type ";;;" (without the quotes) and OK

Dim chk As CheckBox

For Each chk In ws.Checkboxes
   With chk
      .LinkedCell = _
         .TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 0).Address
   End With
Next chk

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Try....

```
Sub Checkboxes()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Input Data")
    Dim Switch As Boolean

    For Each cb In ws.Checkboxes
        If cb.Value = 1 Then
            Switch = True
        Else
            Switch = False
        End If

        MsgBox cb.Name & " Value= " & Switch

    Next cb

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunatelly, this wouldn't help my case as I need to relate to the rows, so I will be old school and use 0 and 1's.

Comment: Take a look at this.....  http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2014/01/14/click-a-cell-to-check-yes-or-no/