# Reference last used Form Control to hide specific rows based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to, upon positive selection of the last used Form Control (Checkbox selected = TRUE, or ComboBox value = Yes - shown in cells C3 and C4 in my sample sheet), show (unhide) any rows from the row below the location of the last used Form Control until the end of the sheet (offset down by 1 row til lastrow) that contain the same string (in column B in my sample sheet) as in the cell adjacent to the Form Control (cells A3 and A4 in my sample sheet).

If the Form Control is negatively selected (Checkbox unselected or = FALSE, or ComboBox value <> Yes), then the rows with the same string should be hidden again.

I'm using Form Controls as I wish to distribute this sheet to Mac users as well, and I want to use the "last used" form control (likely using ApplicationCaller VBA language) so that I don't have to manually enter the name of each Form Control multiple times and create macros for each individual Control (as this sheet will have many many checkboxes and comboboxes). Some small pieces work, but not at all in a consolidated piece of code and not all with Form Controls (some with ActiveX, want to convert that to Form Control compatible code):

Here's what I have:

ActiveX Checkbox and ComboBox code that hides rows when negatively selected (wanting to convert to Form Control language):

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Rows("10:25").EntireRow.Hidden = Not CheckBox1
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    Rows("45:56").EntireRow.Hidden = ComboBox3 <> "Yes"
End Sub
```

ApplicationCaller code that gives the cell location of the last used Form Control (to help set the offset range from the control down):

```vb
Set This = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address)
```

I tried many times to make these two criteria (form control selection and string match) work together. Is there any way to achieve this?

Sample Sheet
[image]

Comment: I'm not experienced enough to find a solution to the above, but just wondering... if perhaps you link all checkboxes to the cell they're over using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41904673/3654325), then hopefully whenever you click a checkbox it will trigger a Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range), which identifies the cell changed. (then do an offset, find and hide/unhide depending on the changed cells value)

Comment: did you mean if checkbox checked(true) or combobox value equal to yes then from list starting at A3 find in column B starting at row 6, if match hide the entire row of the cells that matched, when checkbox unchecked(false) or combobox value equal to no then unhide all the cells that were hidden before, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

A user on ExcelForum has helped me out with an amazingly simple solution, I've linked his answer here and pasted it below for future reference if anyone has this same questions!

From ByteMarks (https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1401191-reference-last-used-form-control-to-hide-specific-rows-based-on-criteria.html) - "If you put this in a standard module and then assign that to both the controls, see if that is what you are after."

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShowHide()
Dim StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long
Dim sHideCriteria As String
Dim ctrlRng As Range
Dim blnHide As Boolean
Dim shp As Shape
Dim c As String
Dim r As Long

If TypeName(Application.Caller) = "Error" Then Exit Sub
With ActiveSheet
    c = Application.Caller
    Set shp = .Shapes(c)
    Set ctrlRng = .Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address)
    sHideCriteria = .Range("A" & ctrlRng.Row)
    StartRow = ctrlRng.Offset(1, 0).Row
    EndRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    If c Like "Check*" Then
        If shp.OLEFormat.Object.Value = xlOn Then
            blnHide = False
        Else
            blnHide = True
        End If
    ElseIf c Like "Drop*" Then
        If shp.ControlFormat.List(shp.ControlFormat.ListIndex) = "Yes" Then
            blnHide = False
        Else
            blnHide = True
        End If
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For r = EndRow To StartRow Step -1
        If .Range("B" & r) = sHideCriteria Then
            .Range("B" & r).EntireRow.Hidden = blnHide
        End If
        DoEvents
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks all!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).